3D marker dynamic loading in Unity - without having to add marker in the built scene
I am trying to figure out if it is possible to dynamically setup 3d markers in Unity and Vuforia. Idea is this - scene is empty (or just has necessary objects for vuforia to be initialized), then I download necessary assets from server and setup the 3D marker and initialize it. This would also make possible to add more markers in the future without rebuilding the project.
I tried putting the .dat and xml files on server but I didn't know how to use them when I download them in the unity project. More complicated solution would be to put the unpacked files from the .dat file (this is random, sometimes it is one mesh with many materials and few folders etc.), but again I wasn't sure how to use this after being downloaded to local storage.
Does Vuforia cloud support 3d markers? from the documentation I think it doesn't

Can you clarify your question and give an example of 3D marker?

For the model I am still experimenting for example I used the samsung s8 3d model for my old phone, it all works fine when I manually setup everything by the tutorial. For clarification I am not sure what exactly but I will try to summarize - I want to be able to dinamically load 3d marker which is hosted somewhere. Imagine having empty ar vuforia scene and you come and the marker is being downloaded and placed on the scene and setup like I did the manual setup by tutorial.

My question was more what you mean with 3D marker. This is not a common term in Vuforia world. I assume you mean a Model Target https://developer.vuforia.com/library/objects/model-targets .

Regarding loading targets at runtime a guide on how to do it is available here https://developer.vuforia.com/library/unity-extension/create-and-load-targets-unity

Thanks for the link, I thought it was just for creating image targets. Yes you are correct I was thinking about Model Targets when I said 3d sorry about that.

No the same logic applies to any target.

I did try using the CreateModelTargetAsync with downloaded .xml file from the bucket but unfortunatelly it creates the game object with ModelTargetBehavior but without the database or model market selected nor available in the list. I am continuing to figure out how to assign them through code, so far I didn't see any property exposed in the ModelTargetBehavior. Also I didn't see how to use the .dat file which should also be downloaded from the bucket

The .dat file should be available in the same folder of the xml file, then Vuforia will load it automatically.

Yes in the mean time I figured it is working automatically. Basically there are some editor errors which are not important because in the build it is working correctly. Thanks for help!
